# Formatting input while typing

Tags: jquery

I want to format input while I type in a european format for numbers which is like "100.000,00"

```
  $(input).keyup(function (event) {

        // skip for arrow keys
        if (event.which >= 37 && event.which <= 40) return;

        // format number
        $(this).val(function (index, value) {
            return value.replace(/\D/g, "").replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");

        });
    });
```

I've tried this one but it's only for ","

i want pure jquery not plugins or anything else

Comment: What should happen if you move the caret and go change a number?

Comment: For it to reformat the field

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jquery Mask number with commas and decimal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35413377/jquery-mask-number-with-commas-and-decimal)